# Dask xarray created from 'isel' operation fails to load values (too slow)

Tags: python, numpy, dask, python-xarray

I have a 4d dask array whose dimensions correspond to (time,depth,latitude,longitude). FYI, this is an oceanic data set.

```
# Create xarray dataset object for ocean temperature (time x depth x lat x lon)

DS=xr.open_mfdataset([outdir + s for s in flist],combine='by_coords',chunks={'xi_rho':25,'eta_rho':25})

DS.temp
```

Output:

```
xarray.DataArray
'temp' (ocean_time: 1456, s_rho: 50, eta_rho: 489, xi_rho: 655)
dask.array<chunksize=(1456, 50, 25, 25), meta=np.ndarray>
```

When I try to load a 1d-vector from this dask array, there are no issues.

```
T=DS.temp
%time
T.isel(ocean_time=0,eta_rho=100,xi_rho=500).values
```

Output (am omitting the values below):

```
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 5.96 µs
```

I now want to select only those (lat,lon) where the ocean floor is deeper than, say, 1000 m.

```
depth_max=1e3;
deep=np.where(DS.h >=depth_max); # DS.h is the depth of the ocean bottom.

# Number of locations where the ocean is deeper than depth_max
xy_num=len(deep[0])
```

This gives me a tuple `'deep'` whose first element `(deep[0])` is a list of all the `'eta_rho'` (latitude index) values satisfying the condition. The second element of the tuple `(deep[1])` is a list of the corresponding `'xi_rho'` (longitude index) values. So, I can construct the `(lat,lon)` index pairs using `(deep[0][0],deep[1][0]), (deep[0][1],deep[1][1]), (deep[0][2],deep[1][2]), (deep[0][3],deep[1][3])`, etc.

This is great because I want to create a single coordinate that sweeps through `(lat,lon)` pairs satisfying the above condition. The goal is to get from `(time,depth,lat,lon) -> (time,depth,gthmax)` where `gthmax` is the new coordinate described abvoe. I do it like this:

```
# Picking only those (lat,lon) where the condition is satisfied
T_deep=T.isel(eta_rho=xr.DataArray(deep[0],dims='gthmax'),xi_rho=xr.DataArray(deep[1],dims='gthmax'))

# Explicitly assign the new coordinate
T_deep=T_deep.assign_coords({"gthmax":range(0,xy_num)})

# Create chunks along this new coordinate
T_deep=T_deep.chunk({'gthmax':1000})

T_deep
```

Output (just showing the dimensions):

```
xarray.DataArray 'temp' (ocean_time: 1456, s_rho: 50, gthmax: 133446)
dask.array<chunksize=(1456, 50, 1000), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Here is where the problem arises. When I try to access values from this new 3d dask array, even at a single point, the command below never finishes completion and I have to end up killing the kernel. I have also tried using `load()` and `compute()`, to no avail.

```
T_deep.isel(ocean_time=0,s_rho=46,gthmax=100).values
```

Any thoughts on where am I screwing up in the conversion from the original 4d dask array to the 3d dask array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no dataset to have a test, and it is hard to say by restricted information. Here is what my first guess.

When you are using the xr.open_mfdataset to load the information, you are actually assigning a new dimension "ocean_time" to the topography variable h. The dimension of "h" should be transferred from [eta_rho, xi_rho] to [ocean_time, eta_rho, xi_rho]. Therefore when working on

```
depth_max=1e3  
deep = np.where( DS.h >= depth_max)
```

the dimensions of deep are not [eta_rho, xi_rho]; in fact, they are also [ocean_time, eta_rho, xi_rho]. I guess, thus, the problem occurs here. You are pushing the coordinate system from [ocean_time, s_rho, eta_rho, xi_rho] to [ocean_time, s_rho, gthmax] by using

```
eta_rho=xr.DataArray(deep[0],dims='gthmax')  
xi_rho=xr.DataArray(deep[1],dims='gthmax')
```

Notice that the length of the dimension "ocean_time" is 1456, where it is way larger than your horizontal dimension (eta_rho: 489, xi_rho:655). I believe this will confuse the xarray/dask and slow down the processes once you want to call the value.

---

Since I got your dataset, let me update my answer.

```
df = xr.open_mfdataset('./*.nc',  
                       combine='by_coords',  
                       chunks={'ocean_time':10}, 
                       parallel=True, 
)                                                                                                                 

temp = df[['temp']]                                                                                            
temp1 = temp.sel(xi_rho=xi_rho,eta_rho=eta_rho)                                                                   
%time temp1.isel(ocean_time=0,s_rho=46,z=100).compute()                                                          
CPU times: user 2.2 s, sys: 1.11 s, total: 3.31 s
Wall time: 3.05 s
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Unfortunately, the data size is too large to share (170 gb). I have checked that `h` only has 2 dimensions `(eta_rho,xi_rho)`.  So, I don't believe that is the issue here. Also, `deep` is a tuple (2 elements only) where the first element stores all the lat-indices and the second element has all the lon-indices. I have confirmed that `deep` correctly picks out the lat-lon indices of the locations where `h` is deeper than 1000 m.

Comment: Then, the question should be on your chunk size.
There are many rules to chunk your array, I am not really familiar with it. But what I will do is "chunk your array larger enough", and "let array vectorize the computation". Hence, I will chunk your array in "ocean_time" and "s_rho". Well, in your dataset, chunk by s_rho is not working since the s_rho does not exist in all of the variables.

Comment: Just wanted to add an update. Based on off-line suggestions from Franke, I found that ipython is able to load those values within a few seconds but my jupyter notebook never could, which is why I always had to restart the kernel. This might not be a jupyter versus ipython problem but might have something to do with how jupyter notebooks are set up on the cluster at my university. Nevertheless, the contrast is interesting. So, my original question remains unresolved but I am upvoting Franke's comments as they were the most helpful.